# symfony, knpLabs/snappy, generate, pdf, font,

Tags: css, symfony, fonts, snappy

I have a question. 
I am using knpLabs/snappy bundle to generate a pdf from a twig template in my symfonyproject.
Everything works fine but the only problem is that it won't load my google-font.
Is it possible to use a google font?
My googlefont is visible in the preview but not in the rendered pdf.

See pictures below:

Preview:

[image]

PDF:

[image]

Can someone please help me out? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use @font-face from CSS or try found a tool to encode fonts to the base64.